# Best practice on where to delete a resource in an inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following code:

```
class Base {
protected: 
    int* ptr_;

public:
    virtual ~Base() { /* delete ptr_ ?? */ }    
}

class A : public Base {
public:
    A() { ptr_ = new int; }
    ~A() { /* delete ptr_ ?? */ }
}
```

I'm having a minor dispute with my colleague.
Which destructor should delete `ptr_`?
I think it should be in `A`, because it's where it is allocated.
He thinks it should be in `Base`, because thats where the pointer is.

Please give possible pitfalls why one method is better than the other (if there is one, and it's not just a matter of taste)

**EDIT**
Alot of people are questioning the design. In practice, the code is much more complicated, and models an Image processing system involving a few cameras.
The role of Base is to manage the resources of the system (A few configurations exist).
Class `A` and other derived types like it decide the configuration of `Base` and initialize the system to a specific configuration. I guess now you can ask if Inheritance is the right choice over Composition. `A` is-a `Base`, just a specific kind, and that is why we chose inheritance. In this case, `ptr_` is a pointer to a specific driver of a camera, which will be decided by the derived type, that is why it is allocated there.

Comment: I think your time arguing this would be better spent arguing whether these classes are well designed or not. If you're having these doubts, the answer probably is "no".

Comment: @Mat My question was regarding implementation details, not time management

Comment: I know. You're looking at the wrong details though. If your design makes people wonder who owns an object, then you should be wondering how to fix that, not where to delete it.

Comment: Don't take @Mat's advice wrong. Your question is on design of the classes and his suggestion is on design of the classes also: you probably want to redesign the classes so that it is more natural for you and others to read and maintain the code. As of time management, consider that this is a one time decision (how the design of the class is), but it might impact quite a few rounds of maintenance and/or refactoring in the future. Giving it a few minutes to think whether it makes sense or there are better solutions will save you time in the long term.

Comment: The `Owner` of the resource should delete it. 'A' has obviously given up ownership to the 'Base'. But you should really not be using pointers. Replace with a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're worrying about code duplication, but I am afraid it clouded your judgement.

I know that DRY get a lot of press (and for good reason) but you misunderstood it. There is a difference between not duplicating *code* and not duplicating *functionality*.

**DRY** is about not duplicating *functionality*. There might be code patterns that look alike, but are used for different goals, those should not be merged as each goal could shift independently (and un-merging is a nightmare). Their ressemblance is *coincidental*.

This is the case here. You arbitrarily force a `int* ptr_` in the `Base` (which does not use it) class because surely all derived classes will need it. How do you know that ? *At the moment* it turns out that all derived classes do need it, but this is a coincidence. They could choose to rely on something else.

Therefore, a *sane* design is to provide an *interface* in the base class, and leave it up to each derived class to choose its own implementation:

```
class Base { public: virtual ~Base() {} };

class D1: public Base {
public:
  D1(Foo const& f): ptr_(new Foo(f)) {}

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr_;
};

class D2: public Base {
public:
  D2(Bar const& f): ptr_(new Bar(f)) {}

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> ptr_;
};
```

On the other hand, *if* the `Base` class was to provide some common functionality that required data members, then of course those could be hoisted up in the `Base` class implementation... though it could be argued this is premature optimization as, once again, some derived classes might choose to do things differently.

Comment: I chose this answer because, while looking for an implementation suggestion, many pointed to look at the design, and in the end i chose to move `ptr` to the derived class.

Answer (score 7):

Each class should manage its own resources. When you have multiple derived classes, each one must remember to free the pointer. This is bad, since it duplicates code.

If some derived class is allowed not to assign the pointer a fresh value, then set it to zero in the base class constructor. If some derived class should be allowed to assign to the pointer the address of an automatic variable, then review your design.

Use smart pointers to make the problem totally go away (when I `grep delete *` in my entire codebase, I find no match :)

Comment: +1 for `grep delete` (I find one occurrence only, in a smart pointer with deep copy behavior I implemented).

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by: ...to assign to the pointer the address of an automatic variable

Comment: @Itsik: `struct B : Base { B(int* x) { ptr = x; } };` and `int a = 42; B b(&a);`.

Comment: Obviously this is bad, but this is not the case. A constructs a specific object via a Factory

Answer (score 6):

The question is one of design more than one of implementation. I tend to agree with your coworker, if the pointer is in the base, it seems to indicate that the base object is *responsible* for management of the resource, rather than the derived type.

As a matter of fact the bit that is strange is the fact that the derived constructor is modifying a base member, it probably makes more sense to pass the pointer to the base constructor in which case the semantics would be clearer: the base receives a resource during construction and is responsible to manage it during it's lifetime.

If the base should not manage the resource, then why is the pointer at that level? Why is it not a member of the derived type?

Note that when managing a resource, you should consider the [**rule of the three**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)<sup>1</sup>: If you have to implement one of *copy-constructor*, *assignment-operator* or *destructor*, then you probably want to implement the three of them (additionally consider implementing a [*no-throw* `swap`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-throwing_swap) which will be handy).

Once you add *copy-constructor* and *assignment-operator* to the mix you will probably see that the natural place to manage the resource is there where it is held.

<sup>1</sup> The rule is generic as there are good reasons not to implement all of them always. For example, if you manage your resources inside members that implement RAII (as smart pointers), you might need to provide *copy-construction* and *assignment-operator*'s as for deep copying semantics, but destruction would not be required. Alternatively, in some contexts you might want to *disable* *copy-construction* and/or *assignments*.

Comment: The base doesnt specifically use `ptr` but all the derived classes of base will need `ptr`. It is in the base to avoid code duplication and declare `ptr` in all the derived classes. It does not allocate it itself because only the derived type knows the exact type. (in my code ptr is not int* but AnotherBase*)

Comment: @ltsik: So you want the pointer in the base class to avoid the duplication of `AnotherBase *ptr;` that is quite innocuous (if any derived class forgets, the compiler will tell), but you are willing to duplicate the `delete ptr;` in all derived types, which is much more dangerous (if one subclass forgets, then you leak resources)? Think beyond code: do you want the pointer in the base class (detail) or do you want to factor management of the resource to the base class? Again, I would pass the pointer in the constructor and manage the whole lifetime there.

Comment: I agree that having the derived classes `delete` is code duplication, and this is why the answers are leaning me towards my colleagues view. Although, any person that implements a new derived will also allocate ptr, so if they allocate it, I expect them to also delete it, and not have to go read the documentation to make sure `Base`s dtor is handling it.

Comment: @ltsik: Again, passing the pointer in construction gives you that: the base object *acquires* ownership of the resource on creation. What makes it *weird* is that the derived objects are *manually modifying the base object members* in one case, so it seems kind of *magicy* that some of the operations are handled in the base. The code smell is not in the base managing the resource but in the derived objects manually modifying *ptr*. You can make ptr private and offer an accessor (reference) and that would make it explicit in the interface that derived objects don't have responsibilities.

Comment: I tend to agree with what you are saying, but if I do actually make it private and offer an accessor, whats the point of `protected` ?

Comment: @ltsik: I did not say that the accessor should be public, if nothing outside of the class hierarchy needs access to the object, then the accessor may as well be `protected`. Also note on the design decisions, that if you move the responsibility to the base, and pass the resource in construction your base is effectively implementing RAII. Without it, you will have problems with exception safety, consider: `Derived2() { ptr = new int; op_that_throws(); }`, because `Derived2` was never fully constructed, `~Derived2` will not be called, and the memory will leak.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, **`ptr_` should be `private`**! (See Scott Meyers *Effective C++*, or any primer on object orientation.)

Now, the question doesn’t even pose itself: only the base class can manage its resource. The derived class can only initialise it by passing a request forward to its base (preferably via the constructor):

```
A() : Base(new int()) { }
```

Comment: Derived class must use it .. I don't see why it should be private

Comment: If `ptr_` is used in base class then shouldn't it be `protected`. IMHO from OP's question, it seems that `ptr_` is intended to be used in derived class also.

Comment: @Itsik That’s a mistake. You are violating basic OO principles here by leaking `ptr_` into the interface (protected *is* part of the classes interface!). You must not do this. Design your base class in such a way that `Derived` doesn’t need to access `ptr_` directly, just those methods that it needs.

Comment: +1 the only thing i would change would be to use an appropriate smart pointer. @Itsik the base would declare methods to mutate and potentially expose the value to the subclasses. it makes perfect sense for the variable to be private.

Comment: @iammilind That’s irrelevant, since the class design is just wrong. Member variables should always be private, no exception. The point is: the OP’s problems go away if he starts to adhere to good OO design.

Comment: @Konrad, by making it `private` is restricting someone to adhere to one particular design. Anyways, that's a matter of another discussion. I agree with you that, `Base` should take care of deleting `ptr_`.

Comment: @iammilind “by making it private is restricting someone to adhere to one particular design” – yes, exactly. *This is a good thing*. Only this way can you make use of the strong type system to prevent errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer deleting it in the Base class because,
If I deallocate it in Derived class destructor(which gets called before Base class destructor) then there is a chance that it can get used accidentally in Base class.

Also, The lifetime of the pointer ends within Base class so that should be the place to deallocate it. In fact, I would allocate the pointer within the Base class and not Derived class.

Best is ofcourse to use **RAII**, and not delte the pointer explicitly, let the **Smart pointers** take care of deallocating themselves.

Comment: Create a pointer in the constructor, manage it, delete it in the destructor. Am I missing something? I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Would you need a Inheritance hierarchy for implementing a Smart pointer/Resource Handling class, where in, You have a pointer created in Base class and allocated in Derived class?

Comment: You don't _need_ one, but does having one make it not a resource managing class? It might not be a dedicated smart pointer class but it seems to have at least one of the same properties.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: If it doesn't need one but still it has one then it it just seems to be a minimalistic code sample from the user, to explain his problem.

Comment: +1 for pointing out chances of accessing deleted pointer in `Base`'s destructor.

Answer (score 1):

ptr_ shouldn't be in the base class because nothing in the base class uses it. It should be in the derived class.

If you must have it there, I agree with you, it should be deleted in the derived classes desteuctor. The base class can't even know if that pointer was even used, why should it delete it?

Comment: This obviously isn't the whole code. Base might not specifically use it but all it's derived classes will need it.

Comment: @itsik are you sure all classes will need it? It's impossible to provide an implementation without it?

Comment: Yes they will all need it. In actual code `ptr` points to a driver of a camera. There is no meaning of the system without the camera.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is the object that creates the resource should delete the resource - it is their responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

To me the best is to have the same object in charge of the allocation and the unallocation.
So in your code, `class A` would be in charge of the `delete` as it performed the `new`.

But: why did `A` allocate `ptr_` instead of `Base`? This is the real question here. There's a problem of design to me as `ptr_` belongs to `Base`. Either it should belong to `A` instead, or `Base` should be in charge of its memory management.

Answer (score 0):

i would do this, using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

```
class RaiiResource
{
private:
   int* ptr_;

public:
   RaiiResource()       {       ptr_ = new int;       }
   ~RaiiResource()       {      delete ptr_;       } 
    int* getResource()      {           return ptr_;        }
}

class Base 
{
protected:
    RaiiResource m_raiiresource;

    void anyMethod()
    {
        int* pIntNeeded = m_raiiresource.getResource();/*when you need the resource*/
    }

public:
    virtual ~Base() {}    
}

class A : public Base {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() { }
    void anyOtherMethod()
    {
        int* pIntNeededAgain = m_raiiresource.getResource(); /*when you need the resource again somewhereelse*/
    }   
}
```

Another way would be using std::shared_ptr that allows managing the scope of life of objects between different objects, which is the case in your case ( Base and A are sharing the need of the object (int) existence)